# CIFS mount from fstab not working

Tags: linux, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux, fstab, cifs

This method used to work with RHEL 5, and 6, so I used to just add this Line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
\\192.168.1.50\V$ /mnt/N    cifs     user,uid=500,rw,suid,username=Administrator,password=password    0    0
```

But now this is not working on RHEL 7.6

I found this link
[CentOS / RHEL 7: How to follow the mount order in `/etc/fstab`](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-follow-the-mount-order-in-etcfstab/). After following I copied `/run/systemd/generator/mnt-N.mount` file to `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-N.mount`. Rebooted but it's still not working.

Contents of `mnt-N.mount`:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Before=remote-fs.target

[Mount]
What=\192.168.1.205\V$
Where=/mnt/V
Type=cifs
Options=user,uid=500,rw,suid,username=Administrator,password=PSCr0cks
```

Comment: that worked, I feel stupid, can you please put that as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\\192.168.1.50\V$` from `fstab` becomes `\192.168.1.205\V$` later. Compare [*fstab-generator interprets backslashes in CIFS mounts*](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89851).

You may try `\\\\192.168.1.50\V$` and it will probably generate a proper mount unit. However the linked discussion (from 2015) states you may experience problems with `mount` then. I don't know if the behavior of the two tools has finally been made uniform.

It's better to avoid backslashes at all and use forward slashes for CIFS mounts:

```
//192.168.1.50/V$
```

Comment: Update I tried //192.168.1.50/V$ in the fstab and I didn't even had to copy /run/systemd/generator/mnt-N.mount file to /etc/systemd/system/mnt-N.mount so apparently all I needed was  //192.168.1.50/V$